# Can an Avalanche Hammer melee basic be upgraded by Ogremight Bruiser (Greater Style)

Tags: dnd-4e, feats

The `Ogremight Bruiser (Greater Style)` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/feat.aspx?id=2376)] allows you to use some powers in place of a `melee basic attack`.

> You can use a power associated with this feat in place of a melee basic attack when charging.

The `Avalanche Hammer` [[ddi](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/item.aspx?id=559)] works with a `melee basic attack`.

> When you charge an enemy and hit with a melee basic attack using this weapon, the attack deals 1[W] extra damage.

Does the upgrade effect from the `Ogremight` mean the attack gets the extra **1[W]** of damage ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No**

There are two relevant phrasings used when things are used like a basic attack.

`Ogremight Bruiser` says (emphasis mine):

> You can use a power associated with this feat **in place of** a melee basic attack when charging.

By comparison, a warlock's `Eldritch Blast` says (emphasis mine):

> This power **counts as a** ranged basic attack. When a power allows you to make a ranged basic attack, you can use this power.

Note the difference: `Eldritch Blast` *is* a basic attack, while an `Ogremight Bruiser` power is used *instead of* a basic attack.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**

The phrases, **counts as** and **in place of** are the same as far as the rules go, substitutions.  The character builder supports this too, you'll find your basic attack bonuses will show up on your **in place of** power cards liked *Wicked Strike*, a fighter At-will

Comment: Do you have a rules source for this? The words themselves do not appear to be synonyms.